# Install fullcalendar purchased version onto Appian Cloud?

Tags: fullcalendar

We have purchased @fullcalendar and we are unsure how to deploy it to our Appian Cloud instances.  We also do not know how to add the license Key.  We reached out to appian support and where informed we needed a "signed" zip file.

Comment: If you have a support question and have paid for fullcalendar premium, please direct your question to the support email address.

Comment: I don't know appian cloud specifically to understand if it has certain deployment constraints, but normally, deploying fullcalendar is simply a case of putting the relevant javascript into your Web page. You can even leave the fullcalendar files themselves on a public CDN. The license key is an option you set in your fullcalendar config code - this is explained and shown in the documentation on the fullcalendar.io website - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/schedulerLicenseKey